# Making an Global Error Handler with type safety in Typescript

Tags: typescript, error-handling

I want to move all error handling into 1 global function to avoid multiple try catch at every place I know we can catch errors with just appending to the `await func().catch()` but a global solution should also work which is :

```
async function errorhandler(func) {
 try{
   const result = await func();
   return [result, null];
 }catch (err) {
   console.log(err);
   return [null, err];
 }
}
```

And using it like:

```
function mainFunction(){
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/"
  const [data, error] = errorhandler(fetch(url));
  if(error) //do something
  data. //no intellisense of methods ?
}

mainFunction()
```

When I do this I am losing all the intellisense.
I have also tried applying some types like this:

```
async function errorhandler(func: () => Promise<T>): any {
 try{
  const result = await func();
  return [result, null];
 }catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  return [null, err];
 }
}

function mainFunction(){
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/"
  const [data, error]: any = errorhandler(() => fetch(url));
  if(error) //do something
  data. //no intellisense
}

mainFunction()
```

But didn't work. Any help would be highly appreciated.

I am expecting to get the autocomplete for all the methods that will available for the data field with type safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with your second attempt.

- The function has no generic parameters, yet you are trying to use `T`
- The return type is just `any`
- The function is `async`, but you are not `await`ing the result
- You also annotated the resulting tuple with `any`

My suggestion, after fixing  these issues, would be to type the return type of `errorHandler` as a discriminated union of `[null, unknown] | [T, null]` which can be narrowed by checking the value of `data` for truthiness.

```
async function errorhandler<T>(
  func: () => Promise<T>
): Promise<[null, unknown] | [T, null]> {
  try {
    const result = await func();
    return [result, null];
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return [null, err];
  }
}

async function mainFunction() {
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/";
  const [data, error] = await errorhandler(() => fetch(url));
  if (!data) {
    data;
    // ^? const data: null

    error;
    // ^? const error: unknown
  } else {
    data;
    // ^? const data: Response

    error;
    // ^? const error: null
  }
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwKYCdfq4AWwEAJgDZ4A8AKgHwAUAUDPElAFwyMCUMAXnowACgQC2qENjr1mvbmPSTp1ANoQEFCgBoYSANYR0AdwgBdGAB8Ya2ns3bzwgN6sYyXGBhu2bKJggyDC42CBawQIwwCbAqMGI0HwA3O5socgIuFhqoeEUyA5aFOapbAC+MFDAyFBEPHi4-L5+ARAg6FQAdBToAOaMjbxlfhlZOY66OPil7uXM88ygkLCJUGiYMOJxEABiHBsQfD7ubUH6uBSCMABERMjIAA4gnAD0rwBWHRCPFMBQ2CInTIeC6yDAj1QARBXQC4leyHQZHQIFeNxGZ2CajINWAekahEsURicWCBOIpEoeEYxyE8GwtSIjCyFF4w3cqDgPAAhDjkMBmmkYHzgCM2O8YAA9AD8VUCwRF3EmzCF5LFMAlMrl7TJ+EI3EMxjMcxwFGkJz8wtx6s1ssxVv53AASmFHoFsCrLWqhbbtedyUrinMFirtqg9gcMEd2UA)

Comment: So we have to await 2 times I thought as we are transferring that logic to external function so external function would await and send us the result. Now I get it as we are also returning a Promise so we have to use 2 times right ?

Comment: Yes, if a function is `async` you have to `await` it to get the result. The call to `fetch` is asynchronous but so is `errorHandler`. Both have to be awaited.